# How can I implement a custom sort a QTableView?

Tags: qt, sorting, qtableview

I have a table (QStandardItemModel) as follows

```
sorted by group
Group | Property 1 | Property 2
A       5            9
A       5            1
A       4            6
B       7            1
B       2            7
B       7            2
```

which I usually sort by the column Group. If I sort by Property 2 in the GUI (via the QTableView), for example, all lines get mixed up, looking like this:

```
sorted by Property 2, but not the way I want it
Group | Property 1 | Property 2
A       5            1
B       7            1
B       7            2
A       4            6
B       2            7
A       5            9
```

I'd like the table to be sorted by the first line of each group, while the order within the group should be the same, i.e.

```
sorted by Property 2
Group | Property 1 | Property 2
B       7            1
B       2            7
B       7            2
A       5            9
A       5            1
A       4            6
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Use a QAbstractProxyModel

Answer (score 0):

Use `QAbstractProxyModel` and reimplement `QAbstractProxyModel::mapFromSource` and `QAbstractProxyModel::mapToSource` methods.